# Positioning Css Animation within Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-animations

I am creating a css animation which I want to put into the bootstrap grid system. Elements in the animation have been set to position: absolute which is making my text cover up the animation when it breaks down on mobile. How do I fix this so that the text goes under the animation when it breaks down?

Here is a link to my code: 
http://codepen.io/aahmed2/pen/NRaPAo

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="animation">
      <div id="human">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="101.223px" height="101.221px" viewBox="0 0 101.223 101.221" enable-background="new 0 0 101.223 101.221" xml:space="preserve">
         <path opacity="0.7" fill="#137CBD" enable-background="new" d="M50.611,0C22.659,0,0,22.659,0,50.611
    c0,27.952,22.66,50.61,50.611,50.61s50.61-22.659,50.61-50.61C101.222,22.659,78.562,0,50.611,0z M69.523,67.95H58.126V50.476
    H43.689V67.95H32.293V25.402h11.396v14.437h14.437V25.402h11.397V67.95z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div id="animal">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="101.109px" height="101.109px" viewBox="0 0 101.109 101.109" enable-background="new 0 0 101.109 101.109" xml:space="preserve">
          <g opacity="0.7">
            <path fill="#D4440B" d="M51.768,36.479c-0.622-2.508-1.032-4.305-1.229-5.391c-0.178,1.007-0.528,2.47-1.052,4.783
        c-0.523,2.311-1.686,6.631-3.48,13.462h9.212l-1.865-6.915C52.92,40.837,52.389,38.987,51.768,36.479z"/>
            <path fill="#D4440B" d="M50.553-0.001c-27.921,0-50.555,22.635-50.555,50.557c0,27.92,22.633,50.555,50.555,50.555
        c27.921,0,50.556-22.635,50.556-50.555C101.11,22.634,78.474-0.001,50.553-0.001z M59.782,66.788l-2.134-8.349h-14.07l-2.191,8.349
        H28.53l14.131-44.02h15.607l14.31,44.02H59.782z"/>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div id="environment">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="101.109px" height="101.109px" viewBox="0 0 101.109 101.109" enable-background="new 0 0 101.109 101.109" xml:space="preserve">
          <path opacity="0.7" fill="#008A2C" enable-background="new" d="M50.556-0.001c-27.921,0-50.557,22.637-50.557,50.556
    c0,27.922,22.636,50.556,50.557,50.556c27.92,0,50.555-22.634,50.555-50.556C101.111,22.636,78.476-0.001,50.556-0.001z
     M63.365,33.938H49.704v7.59h12.902v9.107H49.704v7.59h13.661v9.866H37.562V24.83h25.805L63.365,33.938L63.365,33.938z"/>
        </svg>    
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
     <h3>A Comprehensive Approach</h3>
     <p>One Health recognizes that the health of humans, animals, and the environment all are connected.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.animation {
   position: relative;
}
#human {
   position: absolute;
   top: 15px;
   left: 180px;
}
#animal {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   left: 95px;
   animation-name: animal;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-duration: 7s;
   animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes animal {
   from {top: 100px; left:95px;}
   to {top: 83px; left:140px;}
}
#environment {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   left: 265px;
   animation-name: environment;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-duration: 7s;
   animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes environment {
   from {top: 100px;left: 265px;}
   to {top: 83px; left:220px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm probably a little bit late here, but I got several recommendations.

As already stated, you should use the CSS property `transform` when using `animation` or `transition`. It greatly increases the performance.

You do not need to specify the initial values in the animation, since they are already declared in your class.

For example:

```
#animal {
   top: 100px;
   left: 45px;
   animation: animal 1s linear;
}

@keyframes animal {
   from {top: 100px; left:45px;}
   to {top: 83px; left:90px;}
}
```

Using the following has the same effect:

```
@keyframes animal {
   to {top: 83px; left:90px;}
}
```

---

For the SVGs you could use a spritesheet with symbols and use the `<use>` tag, creating SVG Icons, which you can style and animate with CSS.

### Code Snippet:

```css
#spritesheet {
  display: none;
}
.animation {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;
}
.icon--human,
.icon--animal,
.icon--environment {
  font-size: 6em;
  opacity: .7;
}
.icon--human {
  color: #137CBD;
}
.icon--animal {
  color: #D4440B;
  transform: translateY(100px);
  animation: animal 7s linear infinite alternate;
  ;
}
.icon--environment {
  color: #008A2C;
  transform: translateY(100px);
  animation: environment 7s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes animal {
  to {
    transform: translate(60px, 60px);
  }
}
@keyframes environment {
  to {
    transform: translate(-60px, 60px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class=" col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="animation">
      <svg class="icon icon--animal">
        <use xlink:href="#animal"></use>
      </svg>
      <svg class="icon icon--human">
        <use xlink:href="#human"></use>
      </svg>
      <svg class="icon icon--environment">
        <use xlink:href="#environment"></use>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">
    <h3>A Comprehensive Approach</h3>
    <p>One Health recognizes that the health of humans, animals, and the environment all are connected.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<svg id="spritesheet">
  <symbol id="human" viewBox="0 0 101.223 101.221">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M50.611,0C22.659,0,0,22.659,0,50.611
 c0,27.952,22.66,50.61,50.611,50.61s50.61-22.659,50.61-50.61C101.222,22.659,78.562,0,50.611,0z M69.523,67.95H58.126V50.476
 H43.689V67.95H32.293V25.402h11.396v14.437h14.437V25.402h11.397V67.95z" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="animal" viewBox="0 0 101.109 101.109">
    <g>
      <path fill="currentColor" d="M51.768,36.479c-0.622-2.508-1.032-4.305-1.229-5.391c-0.178,1.007-0.528,2.47-1.052,4.783
  c-0.523,2.311-1.686,6.631-3.48,13.462h9.212l-1.865-6.915C52.92,40.837,52.389,38.987,51.768,36.479z" />
      <path fill="currentColor" d="M50.553-0.001c-27.921,0-50.555,22.635-50.555,50.557c0,27.92,22.633,50.555,50.555,50.555
  c27.921,0,50.556-22.635,50.556-50.555C101.11,22.634,78.474-0.001,50.553-0.001z M59.782,66.788l-2.134-8.349h-14.07l-2.191,8.349
  H28.53l14.131-44.02h15.607l14.31,44.02H59.782z" />
    </g>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="environment" viewBox="0 0 101.109 101.109">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M50.556-0.001c-27.921,0-50.557,22.637-50.557,50.556
 c0,27.922,22.636,50.556,50.557,50.556c27.92,0,50.555-22.634,50.555-50.556C101.111,22.636,78.476-0.001,50.556-0.001z
  M63.365,33.938H49.704v7.59h12.902v9.107H49.704v7.59h13.661v9.866H37.562V24.83h25.805L63.365,33.938L63.365,33.938z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

---

As a final note, you should use the `animation` shorthand instead of separating all the properties, it will reduce your CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `transition: translate()` instead of changing the absolute position of the circles in time. The animation works much smoother then.

```css
.animation {
  position: relative;
}
#human {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 125px;
}
#animal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 90px;
  animation-name: animal;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes animal {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
    transform: translateX(-85px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    translateX(-80px);
  }
}
#environment {
  position: absolute;
  top: 98px;
  left: 168px;
  animation-name: environment;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes environment {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
    transform: translateX(65px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    translateX(80px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="animation">
      <div id="human">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="101.223px" height="101.221px" viewBox="0 0 101.223 101.221" enable-background="new 0 0 101.223 101.221" xml:space="preserve">
          <path opacity="0.7" fill="#137CBD" enable-background="new    " d="M50.611,0C22.659,0,0,22.659,0,50.611
 c0,27.952,22.66,50.61,50.611,50.61s50.61-22.659,50.61-50.61C101.222,22.659,78.562,0,50.611,0z M69.523,67.95H58.126V50.476
 H43.689V67.95H32.293V25.402h11.396v14.437h14.437V25.402h11.397V67.95z" />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div id="animal">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="101.109px" height="101.109px" viewBox="0 0 101.109 101.109" enable-background="new 0 0 101.109 101.109" xml:space="preserve">
          <g opacity="0.7">
            <path fill="#D4440B" d="M51.768,36.479c-0.622-2.508-1.032-4.305-1.229-5.391c-0.178,1.007-0.528,2.47-1.052,4.783
  c-0.523,2.311-1.686,6.631-3.48,13.462h9.212l-1.865-6.915C52.92,40.837,52.389,38.987,51.768,36.479z" />
            <path fill="#D4440B" d="M50.553-0.001c-27.921,0-50.555,22.635-50.555,50.557c0,27.92,22.633,50.555,50.555,50.555
  c27.921,0,50.556-22.635,50.556-50.555C101.11,22.634,78.474-0.001,50.553-0.001z M59.782,66.788l-2.134-8.349h-14.07l-2.191,8.349
  H28.53l14.131-44.02h15.607l14.31,44.02H59.782z" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div id="environment">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="101.109px" height="101.109px" viewBox="0 0 101.109 101.109" enable-background="new 0 0 101.109 101.109" xml:space="preserve">
          <path opacity="0.7" fill="#008A2C" enable-background="new    " d="M50.556-0.001c-27.921,0-50.557,22.637-50.557,50.556
 c0,27.922,22.636,50.556,50.557,50.556c27.92,0,50.555-22.634,50.555-50.556C101.111,22.636,78.476-0.001,50.556-0.001z
  M63.365,33.938H49.704v7.59h12.902v9.107H49.704v7.59h13.661v9.866H37.562V24.83h25.805L63.365,33.938L63.365,33.938z" />
        </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.animation {
   position: relative;
   background-color: orange;
   /* because the content is absolutely positioned the container is 0 height*/
   min-height: 200px;
}
#human {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 90px;
}
#animal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 45px;
  animation-name: animal;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes animal {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
    transform: translateX(-35px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    translateX(-80px);
  }
}
#environment {
  position: absolute;
  top: 98px;
  left: 140px;
  animation-name: environment;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes environment {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
    transform: translateX(35px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    translateX(80px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="animation">
         <div id="human">
            <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="101.223px" height="101.221px" viewBox="0 0 101.223 101.221" enable-background="new 0 0 101.223 101.221" xml:space="preserve">
<path opacity="0.7" fill="#137CBD" enable-background="new    " d="M50.611,0C22.659,0,0,22.659,0,50.611
 c0,27.952,22.66,50.61,50.611,50.61s50.61-22.659,50.61-50.61C101.222,22.659,78.562,0,50.611,0z M69.523,67.95H58.126V50.476
 H43.689V67.95H32.293V25.402h11.396v14.437h14.437V25.402h11.397V67.95z"/>
</svg>
         </div>
         <div id="animal">
            <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="101.109px" height="101.109px" viewBox="0 0 101.109 101.109" enable-background="new 0 0 101.109 101.109" xml:space="preserve">
<g opacity="0.7">
 <path fill="#D4440B" d="M51.768,36.479c-0.622-2.508-1.032-4.305-1.229-5.391c-0.178,1.007-0.528,2.47-1.052,4.783
  c-0.523,2.311-1.686,6.631-3.48,13.462h9.212l-1.865-6.915C52.92,40.837,52.389,38.987,51.768,36.479z"/>
 <path fill="#D4440B" d="M50.553-0.001c-27.921,0-50.555,22.635-50.555,50.557c0,27.92,22.633,50.555,50.555,50.555
  c27.921,0,50.556-22.635,50.556-50.555C101.11,22.634,78.474-0.001,50.553-0.001z M59.782,66.788l-2.134-8.349h-14.07l-2.191,8.349
  H28.53l14.131-44.02h15.607l14.31,44.02H59.782z"/>
</g>
</svg>
         </div>
         <div id="environment">
            <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="101.109px" height="101.109px" viewBox="0 0 101.109 101.109" enable-background="new 0 0 101.109 101.109" xml:space="preserve">
<path opacity="0.7" fill="#008A2C" enable-background="new    " d="M50.556-0.001c-27.921,0-50.557,22.637-50.557,50.556
 c0,27.922,22.636,50.556,50.557,50.556c27.92,0,50.555-22.634,50.555-50.556C101.111,22.636,78.476-0.001,50.556-0.001z
  M63.365,33.938H49.704v7.59h12.902v9.107H49.704v7.59h13.661v9.866H37.562V24.83h25.805L63.365,33.938L63.365,33.938z"/>
</svg>


         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color: pink;">
      <h3>A Comprehensive Approach</h3>
      <p>One Health recognizes that the health of humans, animals, and the environment all are connected.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I really like the smoother transition added by @K. Daniek, so I added that in this answer.  I left background colors in so you could see what is going on.  First the animation needs to be contained within that space (left hand bootstrap column).  Second the reason for the overlap in mobile is because the container of the animation has 0 height.  This is because its children (animated pieces) are positioned out of the normal flow by position absolute.  To make my example work I had to give the animation container a height.  I also adjusted the animation and goofed it up a bit but you get the gist. Hope this helps.

Switch back and forth between full view and smaller view to see what is happening.

Comment: That worked! And I do agree, transition translate did make the animation much smoother.

Comment: If you like it, upvote my solution. I feel a wild hunger for rep points :D

Comment: I can't up vote an answer that does not answer the question.  The question was "absolute which is making my text cover up the animation when it breaks down on mobile. How do I fix this so that the text goes under the animation when it breaks down?". However your answer does make a better animation which was not the question. Feel free to up vote my answer though...since it does answer the question.